# RAILS - Passing parameters to a Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export, rake-task

i need some help :(
well, i need to pass 1 parameter to a rake task. And I'm not 100% sure how to do this, I've tried a lot of things, but nothing actually works.
it's look like this :

```
 {  task :export, [:arg1]  => :environment do
      puts "Exporting..."
      Importer.export_to_csv([:arg1]).to_i
      puts "done."
    end }
```

and then 'export_to_csv' method spoused to get the arg
when I ran in my terminal :
'rake export 1' or 'rake export [1]'
I keep getting the same error-answer:
'rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass'

which is means - he didn't recognize this input.
Thank u guys ahead,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[:arg1]` must be `args[:arg1]` (or whatever name you use as block argument). Here's the code:

```
task :export, [:arg1] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts "Exporting..."
  Importer.export_to_csv(args[:arg1])
  puts "done."
end
```

Usage:

```
rake export[foo1]
```

Comment: it's still dont work,
I got an error :
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `args' for main:Object

Thank you ahead !!!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not useful for debugging. What error are you receiving?

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code I provided you? It looks like you forgot to pass the `|t, args|` block parameters.

Comment: well, now it's work !!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 13):

try this, also have a look on following url. 
 [4 Ways to Pass Arguments to a Rake Task](http://cobwwweb.com/4-ways-to-pass-arguments-to-a-rake-task)

```
task :export, [:arg1] => :environment do |t, args|
  puts "Exporting..."
  Importer.export_to_csv(args[:arg1].to_i)
  puts "done."
end
```

and run it using

```
rake add\[1\]

#OR

rake 'export[1]'
```

Comment: thank you soooo much !!! it's work!